# Jetpack Compose: Textfield and FAB not using full width

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I am trying to put a TextField and a FAB inside a bottomBar using Jetpack Compose.
I wrapped the two with a box, which has the modifier "fillMaxWidth".

But the two controls dont use the full width.

Does anyone know, how to fix this issue?

Here is my Code:

```
    @Composable
    fun ChatView() {
        Scaffold(
            topBar= { ChannelButton() },
            bottomBar = { ChatBox() },
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(10.dp)
        ) {
            ChatList()
        }
    }
@Composable
fun ChatBox() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .background(DiscordDarkGray)
        .fillMaxWidth()
    ){
        Column(modifier = Modifier
            .padding(10.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()) {
            HorizontalCenteredRow(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()) {
                val textState = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
                TextField(
                    value = textState.value,
                    onValueChange = { textState.value = it }
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
                FloatingIconActionButton (
                    icon = Icons.Default.Send,
                    onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                    backgroundColor = DiscordBlue
                )
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(60.dp))
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Here is the Code of the HorizontalCenteredRow:

```
@Composable
fun HorizontalCenteredRow(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier
            .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        content = content
    )
}
```

Here is the code of the FAB:

```
@Composable
fun FloatingIconActionButton(
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    shape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small.copy(CornerSize(percent = 50)),
    backgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(backgroundColor),
    elevation: FloatingActionButtonElevation = FloatingActionButtonDefaults.elevation(),
    icon: ImageVector = Icons.Default.QuestionAnswer,
    iconContentDescription: String = "",
) {
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier.let {
            if (enabled) {
                it.clickable(
                    onClick = onClick,
                    role = Role.Button,
                    interactionSource = interactionSource,
                    indication = null
                )
            } else it
        },
        shape = shape,
        color = backgroundColor,
        contentColor = contentColor,
        elevation = elevation.elevation(interactionSource).value
    ) {
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides contentColor.alpha) {
            ProvideTextStyle(MaterialTheme.typography.button) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .defaultMinSize(minWidth = FabSize, minHeight = FabSize)
                        .indication(interactionSource, rememberRipple()),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        icon,
                        iconContentDescription,
                        tint = if (enabled) {
                            colors().onPrimary
                        } else {
                            colors().onPrimary.transparentize(.6f)
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are HorizontalCenteredRow and FloatingIconActionButton?

Comment: Rows and FAB, which are implemented with preset properties.
In the case of the Row, that everything that is in it is centered.
At the FAB, that it has an icon in it.

Comment: Can you post a screen?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the two controls to my question

Comment: I am not able to replicate your issue using a Row. Post the HorizontalCenteredRow code.

Comment: I added the code of both controls to my question

Comment: Were you able to reproduce my issue?

Comment: Sorry but I'am not able to reproduce.

Comment: So you try it using a Smartphone or a Tablet. The Problem occurs only, when I am testing it on a Tablet

Comment: Ok, the issue is in a tablet. I can replicate it now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using

```
   HorizontalCenteredRow(
          modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
```

the `Row` fills all the space, but it doesn't mean that the children occupy the entire space.
If you want to fill all the space with the children you have to change the default dimensions of them.
For example you can apply `modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)` to the `TextField`.

Something like:

```
        HorizontalCenteredRow(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()) {
            val textState = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
            TextField(
                value = textState.value,
                onValueChange = { textState.value = it },
                modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
            )
```

[image]

Comment: Works fine. Thank you!